# re.M doesnt work for my code

Tags: python, regex

I have this code:

```
import re

s = """line1
   line2"""

print(re.sub("^", "=", s, re.M))
```

and output is:

```
=line1
   line2
```

i.e. reg. expression "^" finds begin of string only, not begin of lines as said in documentation. I do realize the error is in my code but where?

Genneraly I need to replace all the leading spaces of each line in the string.

Thank you!

Comment: The python is "Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're passing the `flags` parameter as positional. Try:

```
print(re.sub("^", "=", s, flags=re.M))
```

Doing what you did passed `re.M` to `count` parameter. Flags is after `count`. Better use keywords in that case.

With that fix, I get:

```
=line1
=   line2
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are passing `re.M` as the fourth argument to `re.sub`, which is the total number of substitutions allowed. It so happens that `re.M` is a numeric constant 8, so your code is equivalent to:

```
re.sub("^", "=", s, count=8)
```

The correct version is to pass `re.M` as a keyword argument:

```
import re

s = """line1
   line2"""

print(re.sub("^", "=", s, flags=re.M))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the flag to `re.compile` to make sure it's not misunderstoody by `re.sub` :

```
print(re.sub(re.compile("^", re.M), "=", s))
```

As an example:

```
import re

s = """line1
   line2"""
line_start = re.compile("^", re.M)
print(re.sub(line_start, "=", s))
# =line1
# =   line2
```